# show all records from mysql database table when date is not selected in java swing form

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I am using java swing and mysql database for my desktop based application.
And i am having following query while giving date filter on reports.
If I have not enter To_date to From_date in JTextField then it must show all records from my mysql database table and if i have entered date then it must show records in between that two dates.
So i have tried (date between To_date and From_date) But its showing records only when i give dates to query otherwise empty.
Would you please suggest me something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try some static value for date column if its null.
I hope below query will help you to resolve your issue.

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE IFNULL(@StartDateParameter, IFNULL(DateColumn,'1900-01-01')) <= IFNULL(DateColumn,'1900-01-01')
AND IFNULL(@EndDateParameter, IFNULL(DateColumn,'1900-01-01')) >= IFNULL(DateColumn,'1900-01-01')
```

Please let me know if you cant solve your issue with this query.

Comment: Can u please explain it bit? and its not working too. Please check out actual query. select sccode, scname, SUM(stota), copen from SalesVoucher, CustomerMaster where scname=cname AND ifnull(@newdate1,ifnull(date,'1900-01-01')) <=ifnull(date,'1900-01-01')AND IFNULL(@newdate2, IFNULL(date,'1900-01-01')) >= IFNULL(date,'1900-01-01')  group by sccode,scname;");

Comment: can you tell me what problem you are facing with your query (which you provided in your last comment)?
if you wish we can chat on http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ for discussion.

Comment: mysql query is not showing any error in my java code but when i give period then also its showing all records from my database table

Comment: Okay, If you think your DB will not have NULL values stored in "date" column then you just need to replace IFNULL(date,'1900-01-01') with date. Remove additional IFNULL(date,'1900-01-01') at all 4 places.

so your new query would be - 
`
select sccode, scname, SUM(stota), copen from SalesVoucher, CustomerMaster 
where scname=cname AND ifnull(@newdate1,date) <=date AND 
IFNULL(@newdate2, date) >= date  group by sccode,scname; `

Comment: Do you have chat access on stackexchange - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users  ?
or email me the complete details with your table definition and few records : my email is : nileshthakkar83 AT gmail

Answer (score 0):

You can use IFNULL ( http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-ifnull/ ) and form your query such that if your parameter is null then you should use your column value for comparison.
e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE IFNULL(DateColumn,@YourParameter) = @YourParameter
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. its showing all records when i have not pass any value but when i give dates its not showing records in that two dates

Comment: are u there? I tried ifnull(date,date between To_date AND From_date) is this correct way?

Comment: No thats not correct way.
Posted one more answer, check it out and let me know if it doesn't help